# get plotBand id from highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I wish to get the plotBand id from the highcharts on hover (mouseover), and change some styles in an li tag with the same id. Is there a way of doing this in highcharts? Not seen so solution so far..

Comment: On mouseover on plotLine you would like to modify styles and get ID ?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.plotBands.events) you'll see that you can add `moseover` event to your `plotBand`.
Then you can get the id by `this.id`.
`this` reffers the `plotBand`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrFsR/)